# Not able to use touch pad after the reboot in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: drivers, touchpad

I have currently installed **Ubuntu 17.10** and it was all going well everything was working fine. But I wanted to add touch pad drivers so I started updating the essential drivers from the terminal. I mainly updated the *synaptics driver*. But when I restarted after updating those things after a long while, my touchpad **stopped working**. While external mouse works perfectly. I have tried many things but nothing seems to sort out the problem. I am using dell laptop(Inspiron 3542). I hope I can get some kind of help from here because other things seemed to be totally unworthy for me.

Comment: Why not remove the drivers!

Comment: even tried that but still it dosent work...

Comment: Well ho will i reMove it any simple method

Comment: see answer here, it may help. https://askubuntu.com/a/1018073/489288