# Touchpad in Dell Vostro 1540 behaves strangely

Tags: touchpad, dell

When I am using touchpad on Dell Vostro 1540 , the touchpad moves abnormally.

I wonder if there is a driver for the touchpad or any solution for this problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as no-repro as it is a hardware problem after losing OEM charger and then using a 3rd party charger (as per the *solution* from external link posted in the accepted answer by OP).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem by buying an original laptop charger.

[This thread on the Dell community forum](https://www.dell.com/community/Laptops-General/erratic-touchpad-when-AC-charger-is-plugged/td-p/3795630) is about this apparently common problem, and led me to conclude that I needed to replace the charger.

Answer (score 1):

I suffered from these issues as well. It behaved normally when booting into Xorg rather than Wayland which is default for Ubuntu 17.10. This is done by pressing the small setting wheel in the login page and choosing **Ubuntu on Xorg**.